# Automate generating SVN Tags

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, svn, maven-release-plugin

I'm working on automating SVN Tag generation through JAVA and need some suggestions to start of with. This is how we do it manually - Check out a maven project/plugin from SVN repo and run a set of maven commands (mvn clean test, mvn release:prepare) to generate SVN tags, **mvn release:prepare** is the final command that would run unit tests, generate the tag and commit it to SVN and I'm working on automating this process.

I had a look at [svnkit](https://wiki.svnkit.com/) api which I can make use of to check out a project to the local file system and find a way to run the set of maven commands to generate tag URL, is there a maven JAVA plugin through which I can trigger maven commands? Or is there a much better way to do this other than JAVA?

I did my research on svn kit but could not find any relevant info to automate the maven process, probably I'm missing out on something.

Comment: You already tagged the question with maven-release-plugin so do you use it?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are looking for **continuous integration**.
I would recommend you to evaluate the use of [Jenkins](https://jenkins.io/), which can be configured to [periodically poll changes from SVN](http://blogs.wandisco.com/2012/01/31/polling-subversion-with-jenkins/) and [launch a Maven build](https://jenkins.io/doc/tutorials/build-a-java-app-with-maven/). Then, if the build succeeded and you decide to release it, you can [perform a Maven release](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/M2+Release+Plugin) from Jenkins, which would take care of invoking the corresponding Maven goals. You can also [configure a post-commit hook](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Subversion+Plugin#SubversionPlugin-Post-commithook) in SVN in order to launch a build after each commit.

Comment: Yes I completely agree with you that Jenkins is the best way to achieve CI but we have some legacy process in our organization and taking the Jenkins route now would change a whole lot of things and could break the legacy process but this has already been considered for the future. For now is there a Java Maven API to perform maven release? Or can I use SVNKIT to auto-create the tag? I did not find anything as such in the svnkit api, also doing a checkout of the projects through svnkit to the work space and triggering the maven build seems inefficient so is there any other way of doing this?

Comment: A tag is a server-side copy (i.e URL to URL), so it doesn't require checkout. If using command line SVN, it would be something like `svn copy -m "Create tag" https://svn.example.com/project/trunk https://svn.example.com/project/tags/tag-xyz` (which you can parameterize into a script). I think it should be possible with svnkit, too.